# Open Source cloud search engine

Tags: hadoop, cloud

I need an open source cloud computing based search engine? Can somebody help me with that?
Thanks.

Comment: * *scratches out buzzwords on a card* * Bingo!

Answer (score 2):

[Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is a open source web crawler and its hadoop based. It has integration with [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) and so the crawled data can be indexed and searched.